# Unable to find a java runtime

Tags: java

I got an error when I run a file exe.

> unable to find a java runtime, please download and install a java runtime from http://www.borland.com/jbuilder/resources/javaruntime.html

I use `Java 1.8.0_151`.

To fix it, I know I can run: `javaw -jar exe_name class_name` in cmd.

`Ex: javaw -jar soflW.exe org.jgraph.JGraphad`, but I don't know how to find the class name?

Comment: You need to add the JRE bin "java" path in the PATH environment variable!

Comment: Might be that you have the wrong runtime installed. If the executable is 32 bits it will likely only "see" a 32 bits runtime. So if you have a 64 bits runtime installed, you still get this error.

Comment: I have found a solution to my problem. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem.

To find class name: I need `zip .exe file` and open it by `winzip`, then open file `manifest.mf` and you can see `class name`.

In my case, I need run with `Java 7` because Java 8 hasn't this class and use `java` instead of `javax` as I said.

In other cases, I can run with `Java 8` and use `javax`. I have not tried with `java` yet.